# Can't validate child entity in APiPlatform

Tags: php, symfony, validation, api-platform.com

I've an `Order` object and an `OrderDetails`. I want to send the order object with the OrderDetails in one POST call. But ApiPlatform never validate the OrderDetails entity. I just get an DB error that the field quantity can not be empty. What do I wrong here?

Here my `Order entity`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=OrderRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`tblInternetAuftraege`")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
#[ApiResource(
   collectionOperations: [
    'POST' => [
        'input_formats' => [
            'json' => ['application/json'],
            'multipart' => ['multipart/form-data'],
        ],
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_POST'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'POST'],
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_POST'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'POST']
    ],
    'GET' => [
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_READ'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'READ'],
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_READ'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'READ']
    ]
],
itemOperations: [
    'PUT' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted(\'ORDER_PUT\', object)',
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_PUT'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'PUT'],
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_PUT'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'PUT']
    ],
    'PATCH' => [
        'security' => 'is_granted(\'ORDER_PATCH\', object)',
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_PUT'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'PATCH'],
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_PUT'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'PATCH']
    ],
    'GET' => [
        'normalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_READ'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'READ'],
        'denormalization_context' => ['groups' => ['ORDER_READ'],'swagger_definition_name' => 'READ']
    ]
],
)]
#[OrangefluidAssert\OrderData]
class Order {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ID",options={"default":0})
 *
 * @Groups({"ORDER_READ","ORDER_PUT", "ORDER_POST"})
 */
private int $id = 0;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=OrderDetails::class, mappedBy="order", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Groups({"ORDER_READ","ORDER_PUT", "ORDER_POST"})
 */
private OrderDetails $details;
}
```

and here the `OrderDetails entity`

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`tblInternetTDSB`")
 */
 #[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: ['GET'],
itemOperations: ['GET']
)]
class OrderDetails {
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ID")
 *
 * @Groups({"ORDER_READ","ORDER_PUT", "ORDER_POST"})
 */
#[ApiProperty(
    writable: false
)]
private ?int $id = 0;

/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="Anzahl", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Groups({"ORDER_READ","ORDER_PUT", "ORDER_POST"})
 */
#[ApiProperty(
    required: true,
    description: 'Die gewünschte Bestellmenge',
    example: '12'
)]
private int $quantity;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Found out what I did wrong.
Here the solution for me.
I had to set the `@Assert\Valid()` to my `$orderDetails`.